# My text keeps coming up in black. Unsure what i did wrong, theres no black text coding....

Tags: css

```
Need help from someone who is familiar with CSS.
```

My code is creating the incorrect color scheme.
 I want the first text/background to be yellow/green and the second to be white/blue. 
I got the blue and green background but the text for both comes up as black. What did I do wrong?

```
----------------------------------
Code 1
-----------------------------------
<p class="webnots_quote1"> <em>
"quote"
</em> </p> <style>
.webnots_quote1 {background: #008000 none repeat scroll;
border-color: #008000;
border-style: inset;
border-width: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
color: #FFD700;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 5px;
font-family: monospace;}
----------------------------
code 2
-----------------------
<p class="webnots_quote2">
<em>
"quote"
</em>
</p>
<style>
.webnots_quote2 {background: #0000FF none repeat scroll;
border-color: #0000FF;
border-style: inset;
border-width: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 5px;
font-family: monospace;}
```

Comment: just checked on localhost, working fine, can you add fiddle/plunkr

Comment: Works just fine for me, maybe declare your styles before you declare your html?  Also, you can shorten up that border stuff into one line.  See my JSFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/2o2364u5/